# Google Maps Geolocation API for wifiAccessPoints returns geolocation not found

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, wifi, google-geolocation

I am using google API to convert wifi data to location data usng POST Method

https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
    {

  "considerIp": "false",
 "wifiAccessPoints": [
  {
   "macAddress": "01:23:45:67:89:AB",
   "signalStrength": 8,
   "age": 0,
   "signalToNoiseRatio": -65,
   "channel": 8
  },
 {
   "signalStrength": 4,
   "age": 0
  }
 ]
}
```

Response I am getting is

```
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "geolocation",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
],
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found"
}
}
```

This is the same code I had used earlier and I was getting latitude and longitude during testing last month. 
Suddenly I get this failure response.
We even tried for Mac addresses that we have tested before all now return same responses.
In above example we are using mac address used in google example. but we also tried the ones that we were getting data before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`404: Not found`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#errors) error response means that no result were returned. However, your request is valid.

You should assume that for some cases, the geolocation is going to fail and you should build an exception handling component that does not fail if errors do occur with geolocation. Your application should continue functioning even if the current location was not correctly fetched due to an error or a user denying permission for the browser to provide the location.

To confirm that this is the issue, set `considerIp` to false in your request. If the response is a `404`, you've confirmed that your wifiAccessPoints and cellTowers objects could not be geolocated.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but we are facing this issue suddenly.
I understand that it fails to return geolocations for some locations, but with any macaddress  wifiAccessPoints we are getting error, even for address that we had run testcases earlier and were getting valid locatons. For any macaddress we are getting  same error. cellTowers we are getting locations as expected . This application is to fetch external device location  so we have set considerIp =false.

Comment: Hey did you find any other solutions? I am facing the same issue with Geolocation

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

> The request body's wifiAccessPoints array must contain two or more WiFi access point objects. macAddress is required; all other fields are optional.

For what I see, you need a macAddress in your second wifiAccessPoint.